# Don't repeat yourself in Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

My current namespace looks like this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :npm_install do
    on roles :all do
      within release_path do
        execute :npm, :install
      end
    end
  end

  task :bower_install do
    on roles :all do
      within release_path do
        execute './node_modules/.bin/bower', :install
      end
    end
  end

  task :build do
    on roles :all do
      within release_path do
        invoke 'deploy:npm_install'
        invoke 'deploy:bower_install'
      end
    end
  end

  after :finishing,  :build
end
```

I wonder if there's an another way to avoid repeating and nesting blocks for `roles` and `release_path`.

How can I write it more concise?

Comment: I don't find enough info on the Internet for Capistrano best practices and code refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the way you wrote it is the standard in Capistrano. For example, the official Rails tasks do it the same way: https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake

```
namespace :assets do
  task :precompile do
    on release_roles(fetch(:assets_roles)) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, "assets:precompile"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  task :backup_manifest do
    on release_roles(fetch(:assets_roles)) do
      within release_path do
        # snipped…
      end
    end
  end

  task :restore_manifest do
    on release_roles(fetch(:assets_roles)) do
      within release_path do
        # snipped…
      end
    end
  end
end
```